# Make a clickable link in salesforce Flow screen

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I have a flow that runs on a button for a contact to create an Opportunity. The flow will check to see if the opportunity exists. If it does not exist, then the user goes through the process of creating an opportunity, if the opportunity already exists it will bring to a screen saying so. My screen here currently has the URL to the Opportunity, but I can't find a way to make it clickable. Is this possible?

I could make it so that when you hit "Finish" the return URL will go to the opportunity, but the other pathways need it to return to the contact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use relative URLs and avoid having to figure out the instance URL as in @denvergreene answer. Here is how it looks in the Spring 20 Lightning Flow UI:

[image]

assuming the record Id you want to link is known to the flow in a variable (in my example `leadId`)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Found it. When editing the screen and the Display Text field there is a little button that is a T with what looks like a selection box around it. Type the text you want (View the Opportunity here). Highlight it, and in one of the fields that showed up you can put in the url. Then you can put in the URL, something like `https://na12.salesforce.com/{!varOpportunityID}`