# How can use a custom label inside a Display Text component in visual screen for URL?

Tags: customlabel, screen-flow

Within 1 visual flow, screen element, I want to display the following text:

> click here for [the latest brochure](https://www.cnn.com)

The link will send the user to read a pdf file.

However, this link is changing often, so, I want to use a custom label to store that value, so I don't need to rebuild the flow each time.

I created the custom label:

> program_brochure_link

Now, within my Display text component, I am trying to use that custom label, as the url with no success

Tried the following:

Using a formula to build the link:

```
HYPERLINK({!$Label.program_brochure_link}, "latest SPIFF brochure", "_blank")
```

But the output on the page is:
[image]

It's neither looks good, nor clickable.

- I tried to use the URL component - but it's for text entry only.

Is it possible ?

Comment: does [this help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70059/make-a-clickable-link-in-salesforce-flow-screen/297682#297682)?

Comment: AWSOME !!! thanks. I used my {!customlabel} as the URL

Comment: both are the same links. both solved it, I can delete this question? or merge ? wdyt?

Comment: the community will close this